# CSS3: Prevent transition-delay when transition is reversed

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create an effect where:

- The cursor hovers over a box
- The bar slides out
- As the sliding motion eases out a title appears
- The cursor leaves the box
- The title begins to disappear as the bar slides back
- The bar finishes sliding back

But instead when the cursor leaves the box the delay is invoked again so the title fades out as the bar finishes it's transition back which looks ugly. How can I achieve the desired effect?

HTML:

```
<div class="slidingbar">
    <h1 class="slidingbar-content" id="title">My Awesome Web App</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slidingbar{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: width 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
}

.slidingbar .slidingbar-content{
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s 1s;
}

.slidingbar:hover{
    width: 100%;
}

.slidingbar:hover .slidingbar-content{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: you have to do tricks...there is no delay between repetition of animations...yet. It will happen, in newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different transitions in the base state and in the hover state.

In this case, the delay should be only in the hover state, and the base state should be un-delayed.

```
.slidingbar .slidingbar-content{
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.slidingbar:hover .slidingbar-content{
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6f52H/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the instructions, try applying the transition on the same element... like this

HTML

```
<div class="slidingbar">
    <h1 class="slidingbar-content" id="title">My Awesome Web App</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slidingbar{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    height: 50px;
}

.slidingbar-content{
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s, width 2s ;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s, width 2s;
}

.slidingbar-content:hover{
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope it help you